# How can distinguish subdomain and maindomain in the link rewrite in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain

in the .htaccess file how can i do this???

1. if user access by main domain the link will be: 
   domain.com/subdomain/category
   domain.com/subdomain/news
   domain.com/subdomain/about
   domain.com/subdomain/product
2. if user access by sub domain the link will be: 
   subdomain.domain.com/category
   subdomain.domain.com/news
   subdomain.domain.com/about
   subdomain.domain.com/product